# Loop through html classes and run an if statement off each one not working ? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to Loop through html classes and run an if statement off each one but my code is not working.

```
$( '.product-name' ).each(function() {
    if($(this).innerHTML.indexOf("Handles") != -1){
        alert('test'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: try using html() instead of innerHTML

Comment: tried it but it's not working does that syntax look right, i mean i'm not getting to no errors in console.

Comment: looks good to me. try logging something inside the each function, just to be sure that it's actually looping

Answer (score 0):

it also looks good to me with html() like Jonas suggested.
try to console.log($(this).html()) inside the each

Answer (score 0):

It works, see snippet below.
Maybe your actual code contains a typo so please check.

```js
$('.product-name').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html().indexOf("Handles") != -1) {
    console.log('Text "Handles" found for id=' + this.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="product-name">Bla</div>
<div id="div2" class="product-name">It Handles It</div>
<div id="div3" class="product-name">Bla</div>
<div id="div4" class="product-name">It Handles More</div>
```